# How to make Acumatica custom action update the current record

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to make a custom action update a custom field on the current record. Eventually I need to work through all the deatils to collect some data, but for now I just need to click the button and have it update the current record. More or less, I think I fail to understand how to get the data that would be in a row level event like this `protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)`

```
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder> LookupShipping;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Lookup Shipping Rates")]
    protected void lookupShipping()
    {

      SOOrder TheRow = Base.Document.Current;

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to update custom fields...

First, you will want to connect to the DAC Extension via:

```
SOOrderExt sOOrderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(TheRow);
```

Then you need to update the field value.  Assuming you are in a Graph Extension, you will need to utilize "Base" to access the cache.

```
Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].SetValueExt<SOOrderExt.usrCustomField>(TheRow, InsertValueHere);
```

Once you update all field values, you need to actually update the cache itself.

```
Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].Update(sOOrderExt);
```

And don't forget to save the record, assuming this button should be a one-stop shop.

```
Save.Press();
```

If you are trying to simply update the values in the existing view, you can do it very easily.

```
TheRow.FieldName = InsertValueHere;
Document.Current.Update(TheRow);
Save.Press();
```

You can see some good alternatives to updating values in HB_Acumatica's answer to where I asked something similar...
[What is the proper way to update values of DAC's retrieved via PXResultset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070800/what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-values-of-dacs-retrieved-via-pxresultset)